# Configuring jhipster to use mysql instead of H2 database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, h2, jhipster

I have CMS based in jhipster and H2 database. This CMS is already used in production. Now, due to performance reasons, we need to change the database to mysql. Is there any guide on how to configure already running jhipster application to use a different database.

Comment: http://www.jhipster.tech/development/#using-a-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not indicate your version of JHipster, so assuming 4.5+.
Edit your `.yo-rc.json` file to change value of "devDatabaseType" to "mysql", and then run `jhipster upgrade --force` to re-generate your app while keeping you custom changes.

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate your version of JHipster, so assuming 4.5+. Edit your ".yo-rc.json" file to change the value of "devDatabaseType" to "mysql", and then run `jhipster upgrade --force` to re-generate your app while keeping your custom changes.